# Python rpg adivce?

Tags: python

I started coding an RPG engine in python and I want it to be very scripted(buffs, events). I am experimenting with events and hooking. I would appreciate if you could tell me some matured opensource projects(so i can inspect the code) to learn from. Not necessarily python, but it would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have better luck asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daenyth suggested, [pygame](http://pygame.org/) is a great place to start.  There are plenty of projects linked to on their page.

The other library that is quite lovely for this type of thing is [Panda3D.](http://www.panda3d.org/)  Though I haven't yet used it, the library comes with samples, and it looks like there is a list of projects using it somewhere.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at `pygame`, it's pretty common for this sort of thing.